# Getting an Error in my Manifest file on React App

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am brand new to React, and am following a tutorial on Sololearn. When I created my own project, and opened it in VS code, I ran it with Live Server. It worked just fine for a while, then suddenly quit working and said that I had an error in my Manifest File and line 1[Image of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKTnY.png)
I did not touch the manifest file, I hadn't even opened it yet. I tried creating a whole new project, and got the same error right off the bat. Anyone have any suggestions on how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

There will be a reference to manifest.json in project,fle or resource itself does not exist.

and check whether you've any link tags with rel=manifest same of

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.webmanifest">
```

.webmanifest extension is specified in the Media type registration section of the specification, but browsers generally support manifests with other appropriate extensions like .json.

ie

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

and remove it from the code to stop the error.